# How to lazy load route with react location?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, lazy-loading, react-suspense, react-location

I am quite new to React, and I have a project that uses `react-location`

I would like to load some routes lazily only if the path is activated.

My current config is:

my base routing module

```
export const routes: Route[] = [
  ...HomeModuleRoutes, // I want this to be instantly loaded.
  ...LazyRoutes, // I want this to be lazy loaded.
  { path: '/', element: <Navigate to="/home" /> },
];
```

those 2 constants look like this :

home.routing.ts

```
export const routes: Route[] = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    element: <HomeTemplate />,
    children: [
      {
        path: '/',
        element: <HomePage />,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

lazy.routing.ts

```
export const LazyRoutes: Route[] = [
  {
    path: 'test',
    element: <LazyTemplate />,
    children: [
      {
        path: '/',
        element: <LazyList />,
      },
      {
        path: 'add',
        element: <LazyAdd />,
      },
      {
        path: 'detail',
        element: <LazyDetail />,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I don't quite see documentation or an example on this, is it just wrapping the component with `<Suspense>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should import your component with `React.lazy` like:

```
const HomeTemplate = React.lazy(() => import("./HomeTemplate "));
```

check this example for react-router v6 [lazy loading](https://stackblitz.com/github/remix-run/react-router/tree/main/examples/lazy-loading?file=src/App.tsx)